# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja' while installing opencv on mac

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, modulenotfounderror, ninja

Im trying to install opencv module using pip.

Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [894 lines of output]

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying 'Ninja' generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
    Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
    CMake.
  
    Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
    CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
  
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Running
  
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/ninja' '--version'
  
    failed with:
  
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/ninja", line 5, in <module>
        from ninja import ninja
  
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ninja'
  
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying 'Ninja' generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have already installed ninja as well. Please help.

Comment: "I have already installed ninja as well." - Have you installed ninja as a separate **tool** or as a Python **module**?

Comment: I have used pip install ninja command to install it.

Comment: Are you sure that on your system `pip` executable works with **Python 3**? On my system `pip` works with Python 2, and `pip3` - for Python 3.